# How to duplicate rows based on columns? Google sheets (only formulas please)

Tags: google-sheets, split, spreadsheet, flatten, google-query-language

I have something like this:

| Item | Color | Id |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TEST1 | WHITE | ID001 | ST01 | ST02 | ST03 |
| TEST2 | RED | ID002 | ST02 | ST03 |  |

And i want to have something like this:

| Item | Color | Id |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TEST1 | WHITE | ID001 | ST01 |
| TEST1 | WHITE | ID001 | ST02 |
| TEST1 | WHITE | ID001 | ST03 |
| TEST2 | RED | ID002 | ST02 |
| TEST2 | RED | ID002 | ST03 |

So basically based on the last 3 columns values, i want to duplicate rows and assign a value from those columns to each row created.

I was trying to use transpose and split formulas, and some other things, but i couldn't get to the result that i want..if is not possible please let me know also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(QUERY(FLATTEN(IF(D1:F="",,A1:A&"×"&B1:B&"×"&C1:C&"×"&D1:F)), 
 "where Col1 is not null"), "×"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  let vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
  let vA = [];
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    if(r.length > 4) {
      let t = r.slice(0,4);
      let u = r.slice(3);
      u.forEach((v,j) => {
        let x = r.slice(0,4);
        x[3] = v;
        vA.push(x);
      });
    } else {
      vA.push(r.slice());
    }
  });
  sh.getRange(2, 1, vA.length, vA[0].length).setValues(vA);
}
```

Sheet 0 before:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 6 | 14 | a | b | c |
| 19 | 16 | 16 | a | b | c |
| 2 | 16 | 1 | a | b | c |

Sheet 0 after:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 6 | 14 | a |  |  |
| 6 | 6 | 14 | b |  |  |
| 6 | 6 | 14 | c |  |  |
| 19 | 16 | 16 | a |  |  |
| 19 | 16 | 16 | b |  |  |
| 19 | 16 | 16 | c |  |  |
| 2 | 16 | 1 | a |  |  |
| 2 | 16 | 1 | b |  |  |
| 2 | 16 | 1 | c |  |  |

Comment: erm..  "only formulas.." was mentioned in the title.. ( :

Comment: I'm not voting... just a heads up.. (nothing personal, just business)  great solution btw..  /(^_^)

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the tag.. Thanks for sharing the script code, if i cant figure out a formula i will have to use a script approach